# regular expression to match a number on a String of numbers that are separated by spaces

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as:

```
String s = " 10 5 15 55 5 ";
```

and I'm trying to get the number of repetitions of a number (in this case 5), using a regExp, so my approach is the following:

```
long repetitions = s.split(" 5").length -1;
```

but this is not working, it also matches 55.

If I use spaces in both sides of the number, things like:

```
String s=" 10 10 15 5 ";
long repetitions = s.split(" 10 ").length -1;
```

it doesn't work, it only counts one instance of 10 (I have two).

So my question is which regExp could be able to count both cases correctly?

Comment: You could try with `split("\\b5\\b")`.

Comment: @Codebender probably because space between `_10_10_` is being consumed by first `_10_` which prevents second `_10_` from being matched (since space at its start can't be matched again - this could be solved with look-around, but `\b` is simpler).

Comment: This works fine, thank you.
But could you please explain me why does it work, I'm kind of newbie with regExp and i would like to know how they work

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern-matching with the regex `'\b5\b'` that uses [word-boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to look for the `5`'s that are not "part of something else:

```
String s = " 10 5 15 55 5 ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\b5\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int countMatcher = 0;
while (m.find()) { // find the next match
    m.group();
    countMatcher++; // count it
}
System.out.println("Number of matches: " + countMatcher);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Number of matches: 2
```

You can do the same for the `10`'s and etc.